# Short way to indicate pedaling every bar

Tags: piano, sibelius

I am writing a piano score in Sibelius, and I need to hold and lift the pedal every bar. But writing it explicitly makes the score heavy so I need a quick notation that means the same thing. [image: Pedal every bar]
Here I added a text with 3 _ like "etc.", but I don't think that's rigorous. (I am not using the pedal line with the lifting arrow because I find this even heavier than the "Ped. *" notation)

Any ideas ?

Comment: Just try "_simile_" or "_Pedale simile_" where the next Ped marking would go.

Comment: Because it's arpeggiated over the same chord, is there actually a need to mark it? I think most pianists would use the sustain pedal as a matter of course, given these circumstances, and instinctively know when to change pedal.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that ! And yes, it's pretty obvious but I wanted to write it, and it's still good to know for less obvious scores :-)

Comment: @Patrx2 That seems to be an answer rather than a comment and not just any answer, but the accepted answer. Could you maybe make it an actual answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would mark in the pedal for 1-3 occurrences, whichever is long enough to establish the pattern clearly, then mark "*simile*" or "*Pedale simile*" where the next pedal mark would fall.